# Problems with some inputs

Tags: javascript, html, input

Does anyone know how can I make this http://prntscr.com/9z7pk with HTML and JS? I made this image so you can understand better what I mean.
I already have this done with 2 multiple select inputs but I don't know how can I insert in  html to put the checkbox.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: +1 for the effort put into the question, but I still think you should show us some HTML that you've tried to get it to work with.

Comment: You cannot add checkboxes into a multiple select. You will need to implement a JS widget yourself for the right list.

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself having a lot of these complex widgets in your application you should look into a framework like [extJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs) or other similar frameworks. It will save you headaches and will prevent you from reinventing a wheel that has been reinvented too many times already.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately a multiple select won't let you inject tickboxes or other arbitrary content into menu items - it relies on the OS-native multi-select hotkeys (typically shift and control).

What you could try is styling both items as `ol` or `ul` lists, and the document items as `li` elements within them. Whenever you add an item to the right-hand list, render a new `li` element and update an `<input type="hidden" />` with a comma-delimited list of selected items.

Depending on how you want the interaction to work, you could:

1. Implement add/remove buttons as depicted, requiring you to implement multi-selection in the lists yourself. A widget framework such as extJS (as zi42 mentioned) can help with this.
2. Put an "add" link next to all items in the left box and a "remove" link next to all items in the selection box, except for the mandatory items.
3. Dispose of the dual boxes and instead place checkboxes against every item in a single, unified list, excepting the mandatory items which should have a checked-but-disabled checkbox input.